# TextEdit says a file is locked but Finder says it's not and I have permissions to write

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions

This file shows as follows in Finder:

[image]

But in TextEdit it says it's locked, and trying to change this fails:

[image]
[image]

It's a project from GitHub/NPM I just want to play with changes locally, not muck about with forking. How can I just make the files writable?

I also tried `sudo open -t index.js` with the same result.

Comment: my workaround is to copy the whole thing elsewhere and manually run the .js file but I'd still like to know

Comment: I don't know the answer, but there are two important hints in what you posted: First, the Info window says "You have custom access", which means the file permissions are set in some way that's more complicated than the Info window knows how to display. Second, the error dialog from TextEdit says "You don't have permission to write **to the folder** that the file index.ls is in", which means that it's permissions on the folder it's in, not the file itself, that really matters. And actually, since it looks like the file is on an external drive, that might matter too.

Comment: So here are some additional things to look at: what format is the JDX_MX100_1 volume in and how is it mounted? Also, in terminal, run `ls -leO@d` on both the file itself and the directory it's in, and add the results (in code format for readability) to your question.